# How can you find the radius from a 2D canvas width in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, game-physics

I have an object that spins perfectly around a circle non-dynamically with the following code.

```
    Radius = 4.7f;
    angle += .25f;

    float x = Radius * Mathf.Cos(angle);
    float y = Radius * Mathf.Sin(angle);
    float z = 0;

    ball.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);
```

I wish to get a radius of the circle dynamically and have the circle as a UI image inside of a canvas. The width of the UI Image is 125 and can be seen by the blue arrows. The logic I though that would work would be to have radius = width/2.

125/2=62.5, which is not close 4.7f. What else am I not taking into account? Scaling or pixel image sizing?

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `BackgroundImages` also has `Scale` = `3`. so you have to also do `(125 / 3) / 2` ... and since this still is not `4.7` ... what exactly are the settings of the parent canvas? Does it have any Scales other than `1,1,1` ?

Comment: My Parent canvas has 0.02574536 scaling x and y. The child parent OutterWheel had scaling of 1.29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to account for the scale of the image (as @derHugo suggested in comment)

But you also need to account for the fact that your canvas will also apply a scale on the units, depending on how you set it.

A good solution is to use `RectTransform.GetWorldCorners`. This will allow you to know the world coordinate of your circle without having to do the scale computation yourself.

```
Vector3[] v = new Vector3[4];
rt.GetWorldCorners(v);
var radius = v[0].x - v[2].x; // Not sure about the order of the corners, the indices might be wrong
```

Another comment: your code is framerate dependent: you add 0.25 degrees every frame. Meaning that the FPS will impact the speed of the rotation (with 60 fps, you will rotate 0.25 * 60 = 15 degrees per seconds. But with 30 FPS you will rotate 0.25 * 30 = 7.5 degrees per seconds)

To be framerate independent, you can do a simple computation using `Time.deltaTime` (this is the time the last frame took to completely render)

Instead of `angle += .25f;`

Do that:

```
var anglePerSeconds = 15; // Choose the angular speed you want
angle += anglePerSeconds * Time.deltaTime;
```